# Unity 2.1 with asp.net concurrency issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, unity-container

We are using Unity 2.1 in Asp.net application.

We are using following code in BeginRequest of Global.asax:

```
public IUnityContainer GetContainer()
{
  EngineContainer container = new EngineContainer(_correl);
  container.RegisterInstance(CORRELATION, _correl);
  foreach(DependencyTypeMap typeMap in _typeMapList)
  {
     SetupDI(container, typeMap);
  }
  return container;
}

private void SetupDI(EngineContainer engContainer, DependencyTypeMap map)
{
     foreach (var m in map.Maps)
    {
        List<object> args = new List<object>();
        args.Add(engContainer.CorrelationInfo);
        if (m.Item3 != null && m.Item3.Count() > 0)
        {
            args.AddRange(m.Item3);
        }           
        if (m.Item4 != null && m.Item4.Count() > 0)
        {
            args.AddRange(m.Item4);
        }
        engContainer.RegisterType(m.Item1, m.Item2, new InjectionConstructor(args.ToArray()));
    }

    if (map.IsloggingEnabled)
    {
        foreach (var type in map.TypesToIntercept)
        {
            engContainer.SetupForInteception(type);
        }
    }
}
```

Issue: 
The value being passed to RegisterInstance is a session id. In one of the scenario the value being passed to RegisterInstance is user A's id. However, what we get in the Controller is user B's id. So, when Unity is creating Controller instance, incorrect session id is being supplied to the Controller.

Question:
Is RegisterInstance thread safe? 
What could be the cause of problem that I am facing

Comment: Setup container only once, in Global.asax/Application_Start.

Comment: If I setup the container in App_Start, I wont be able to inject a correlation id.I need it to be injected at every request so that it is available to my app/db layers. Use of RegisterInstance in my scenario is ineveitable

Comment: You can use either child container to setup only request specific part. But this would be a workaround and still incorrect. Correlation id is a runtime/context value, composition root (container setup) isn't. It configures the dependencies between types, kinda compile-time information.

Comment: You may want to google on this subject. I'm not that good in explaining the theory like Ploeh or Steven the .Net Junkie are. Also DI and multi-tenant asp.net applications, these are similar subjects in terms of DI setup.

Comment: You can instantiate the correlation id related component in the beginning of each request still. And pass it to either its ctor or some init() method. You don't need to configure container every time, which is always a time consuming task and should be performed once until this is really necessary